# How to get user information from Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am a new Android Facebook developers, I have problem with the [first example of Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). The code works if my phone don't have Facebook app install, but if my phone has Facebook install, it doesn't return the user name.

Does anyone know how to do that?

What I need to add in onActivityResult to get user information?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter the correct key hashes in the facebook app? I had the same problem, it seems that if the facebook app is not installed (and you go through the web login screen) facebook still allows you to login even if you have not entered the key hashes correctly, however if the app is present and the key hash does not match you get in exception and the result you get back is null.